# Strange behavior with SVG CSS3 animation

Tags: css, animation, svg

I should preface this by saying that I am brand new to the world of SVGs.  I'm playing around with a rather simple experiment using SVGs and CSS3 animations.

I have created the SVG in Inkscape and saved it as a plain SVG.  I've then put it into HTML to  play around with some CSS3 animations.

As you can see from my link below the whole SVG bounces strangely, this can be removed by removing the .arm class from the CSS.  (which stops the single red circle group that has an arm class).

The problem is that I want the red circle groups to animate (spin) whilst the entire larger group is also spinning.

Any ideas or blatant things I may be doing wrong?  (I do realize it's not the best SVG but I was just experimenting).

http://codepen.io/Fernker/pen/cwvfB

Note 1:  After playing around a bit more if I remove either .arm or .center CSS rules then the wobble stops, but together they produce the wobble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I fixed it for you (kind of).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/unmfE

Basically I hacked it so it works, but you'll need to wrap your SVG in another container and have that rotate from center.  If you animate too far down the nest, it will be affected by siblings.

Comment: Good enough for me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the shape is not creating a perfect circle when spinning, therefore shifting the center whilst spinning causing the wobble.

Comment: Is it weird though that I can spin the larger object and smaller objects separately just fine (with no wobble)?  I also created another SVG (same design) using another SVG editor and had the exact same problem.  I've now moved onto plan B, just using images.